# Android OS stablity/Stress testing

Tags: android, testing

I am currently working for Mobile OEM, our mobiles are based on Android. I want to test stability and stress the Android OS of the mobile. Currently, we Do soak testing, monkey test. I am wondering if there is any other way to test the stability of the Android OS

Comment: Hello Nagesh, what research have you done?

Answer (score 0):

this is a list that I try to test with every app I develop:

1. Orientation Changes
2. Offline mode while doing activities that require connectivity
3. Check behaviour in multi-window mode
4. Kill app while in background
5. Add network delays and latencies
6. Clear cache and data and check failures
7. Update app and see what lingers from the previous version
8. Background the app and test how the services work in Nugat, Oreo and Pie
9. Enter Doze mode/App Standby and see how the app recovers from that
10. Monkey test
11. Layout inspection in different devices, screen sizes and Android versions.